# Push items in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm working on `school-app`. person enter students **`marks`** from frontend and I've to store it in my backend. I know my data-structure is quite bad. but this is only way I can comfortly use and fit it in my front end application/website.

**[codeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cdn-oiuz7)**

**Full Code:**

```
//This data is already set need to push information in this array.
let student = [{
  "detail": {
      "name": "Mark",
      "surname":"widen"
  },
}];


//formatting the query in json.

  const keys = Object.keys(query)[0].split(",")
  const values = Object.values(query)[0].split(",")

  const newObj = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      newObj[keys[i]] = values[i]
    }

//  I've to push it along with "academic-year". so,

     for (let a = 0; a < newObj.length; a++) {
       const year = a + "st-Year"
       console.log(year) // Expected Output: 1st-Year and 2nd-Year
    }

// How to run this both for-loop synchronously way ?? AND

//pushing with "ObtainedMarks" and "year" (Error over here)
  student.push({
      ObtainedMarks: {
          year : [  
              { physics: newObj }
          ],

          year : [
              { physics: newObj }
          ]
      }
  })

console.log(student) //Here's I want expected Output
```

**Expected Output:**

```
let student = [{
  "detail": {
      "name": "Mark",
      "surname":"widen"
  },

  ObtainedMarks: {
    "1st-Year": [
              { physics: { "marks": "500" } } //Physics subject is default.
          ],

          "2nd-Year": [
              { physics: { "mark": "200" } } //Physics subject is default.
         ]
   }
}];
```

I want to push returned data in student array. with `1st-Year`
and `2nd-Year's` **for-loop**.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Sophia, if you could explain better what the actual problem is it will help people to assist you and provide an answer. Also you Sandbox links have no code in them, if you could provide a working example of the problem and update your links this will help you greatly.

Comment: Hi, I want my expected output. But I've problem regarding pushing `obtainedMarks` to student array

Comment: I need to run both `for-loop` asynchronously and push the returned data in `student` array.

Comment: `async await` is your friend. You could create a method to fetch the data with async await and then just inside there you await the other partial data and you return the whole combined object then.

Comment: Yes, I know but I also have in making expected output `array` structure.

Comment: How do i push `year` value in my output expected array ?

Comment: You create the object "ObtainedMarks" first and then you fill it like ObtainedMarks["1st-year"] = x ... later you just push the ObtainedMarks object to student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the conversion in your `for-loop`

```js
let student = [{
  "detail": {
    "name": "Mark",
    "surname": "widen"
  },
}];

let query = {
  "marks,mark": "500,200"
}

const keys = Object.keys(query)[0].split(",");
const values = Object.values(query)[0].split(",");

const marks = {}

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  marks[i === 0 ? `${i+1}st-year` : `${i+1}nd-year`] = [{
    physics: {
      [keys[i]]: values[i]
    }
  }];
}


student.push({
  obtainedMarks: marks
});

console.log(student);
```

Alternative way: `map` through the `keys` and create an object `from entries` after manipulating the data.

```js
let student = [{
  "detail": {
    "name": "Mark",
    "surname": "widen"
  },
}];

let query = {
  "marks,mark": "500,200"
}

const keys = Object.keys(query)[0].split(",");
const values = Object.values(query)[0].split(",");

const marks = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => {
  return [
    i === 0 ? `${i+1}st-year`: `${i+1}nd-year`, 
    [{ physics: { [k]: values[i] }}]
  ];
}));

student.push({
  obtainedMarks: marks
});

console.log(student);
```

Comment: Hi @axtck, I need `1-Year` and `2-Year` in `for-loop`. I've tried for-loop way in my code because even if there is 10 years entry and mark, then it will not be an problem. it just increase with `+1` and give my result. I hope you understand that :)

Comment: @sophia I updated my answer using a for loop